# Are video game questions appropriate for superuser?

Tags: discussion, faq, video-games

Or is it time to create another site?

questions could be general discussion or tips/tricks

Comment: I personally think this could be a real successful SO engine instance.  The only worry I would have would be young gamers being immature on 'teh formz'.  It would probably require some real dedicated moderators, possibly some more automated moderation, and maybe some filtering of the comments for language.  BUT, i think the engine would fit it well for gaming related questions.

Comment: Limiting write access to people how have accounts on the others sites already would get around many of these issues. Intelligent discussions about video games, what works, what doesn't would be interesting, particularly to anyone in the industry and there aren't many of those types of sites around!

Comment: Another site: http://smartergamer.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Current site: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 26):

**The official stance is now that videogame questions are not allowed on Super User.**

1. console gaming questions are not allowed (no computer involved)
2. pc/mac purely gaming questions are not allowed
3. pc/mac *peripherally* gaming related questions *may* be allowed

Example of #3

- "I am having trouble getting my router configured to let my home PC share videos to my Xbox (allowable because a regular home PC is involved)

Update: SU FAQ updated, close reason "purely videogame or console gaming related" added

Comment: Okie dokie. Hopefully there'll be a gaming site at some point. Can I petition for him to be represented by Jar Jar Binks?

Comment: You do realize that the Xbox is just a highly specialized Win2k computer? Right?

Comment: What about, "Which unnecesary services I can turn down for gaming?"

Comment: So then when will we be seeing tetrisstackoverflow.com, jeff?

Comment: I propose `endgame.com` or `gameover.com` --both appear to be sorta open at the moment. Why not a Trilogy in Four parts (or, Five counting Meta), its been done before (you know).

Comment: Can I suggest that questions that are internal to the game are banned, but questions that treat the game like any other app (e.g. "how do I open this port" or "this game won't run on my PC" or, back in the day, "how do I free up enough memory in DOS") are perfectly legitimate....

Comment: I like Richard's comment...I don't think that a gamefaq style site is appropriate...but a place where questions like that (or my current question, 'why the $*()! won't Civ4 run in Win7?) are appropriate.

Comment: Plenty of examples on Superuser where numbskulls desperate to use their powers (however small) have used this rule as an excuse to close questions that are not "purely videogame related" (leaving aside the technicality that games played on a PC aren't *videogames* anyway), tips on improving the performance of a PC for playing a game are the same as tips for improving it's performance at, for example, video editing. Yet the game related ones get closed.

Comment: May I ask for a ruling on questions relating to steam. I believe they're in #3. If it installs incorrectly, or runs crazy, or can't be migrated to a new windows install isn't that a fair question? It's mostly for downloading and updating (and paying for) games, but also allows chatting with friends and downloading media (usually game videos). I see some are accepted and some are closed.

Answer (score 11):

Quite frankly, I'd say no. There are millions of sites devoted to video games, and super-user is devoted to tips-and-tricks for using your computer, not (IMO) how to pass level four in... DROD.

Comment: It is more then tips and tricks. It is for troubleshooting and assistance as well :).

Comment: Well, if you're having a problem with getting those programs to RUN or CONFIGURE. I'd say go for it.

Answer (score 7):

There is quite a few already, and as long as it is PC or Console based I see no reason why they can't be posted. I know there was a thread on the PS/3 on the first day already.

If it does not meet the criteria of the site on a per question basis it will quickly be voted to close either way.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>The [about page](https://superuser.com/about) on SuperUser states (as it's very first line):</strike>

> Super User is a Q&A site for computer enthusiasts that's free

So I'd assume that questions about games and games consoles are allowed. After all what are consoles but computers?

**UPDATE**

This answer is now irrelevant due to recent changes to the [SuperUser faq](https://superuser.com/faq) that banned console and computer game questions.

Comment: Actually the original Xbox was just a specialized Win2k computer.

Comment: @Brad - I rest my case ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Or is it time to create another site?

In answer to this question, I think this thread has shown a terrific reason to have a gaming branch of the Stack Overflow group of sites.  Gaming questions shouldn't be on Superuser at all, I agree, it's just way too specific.

But if there are so many people who need a place to ask gaming-related questions and if there is no other forum for gamers on the internet that isn't laughably rude or unhelpful, I can't think of any bunch of people better than the Superuser et al userbase to answer questions in a mature and helpful manner.

Comment: +1 for this, we need a gaming SO. All the other gaming sites suck, they don't even come close. Gamefaqs.com? Are you serious?

Answer (score 4):

[GameLegend](http://gamelegend.com), a new Stack Exchange site devoted to gaming, is coming soon.

Comment: "The current target date is September 1st, 2009.". Okay, this could mean all and nothing. Let's wait and drink some tea meanwhile :)

Comment: It opened. 52 questions at the time of writing. There is also SmarterGamer, http://smartergamer.stackexchange.com/questions. 52 questions at the time of writing.

Answer (score 3):

Jeff has just been through and closed a bunch of PS3/Xbox related questions, so it seems the answer is 'no'.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the answer should be NO, as if you allow PS3 you have to allow Xbox and Wii. Then  to be fair you have to allow discussion on PSP, and Nintendo DS and iPhone games, and it then becomes a very slippery slope.

Comment: That's not exactly a good reason to restrict video games.  A better reason is simply stating that it doesn't fir the scope of being a "computer enthusiasts and power users", since playing games is more of a casual activity.

Answer (score 3):

Go to a video game site, and look at what's available, and the questions that are asked.  The questions are typically either noise or how to play the game better.  There is no purpose other than to play the game.

Now, look at S[OFU].  The questions are typically on how to accomplish something.  What "something" is varies widely, and the method of accomplishment does, but questions are normally task-oriented.

That, I think, is the basic difference.  So, I'd be happy with questions on programming games in SO, setting up game servers in SF, or configuring a system in SU, but not questions on how to beat the second gym leader in Pokemon Platinum.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going ask here, since my other question was deemed, after 12 revisions of twisting and turning my question all around, not representing my original intended question anymore, a duplicate (duh!).

How are video games not software? As far as I know Superuser is about software and hardware related questions.

Surely you realize that video games ARE software with intent to entertain. I fail to grasp the logic behind the exclusion of video games from superuser.

Comment: They produce discussions and noise. Both are not appropriate for SU. Follow the dupe link to your question. It's there for a reason...

Answer (score -1):

Super User do **not** allow video game questions. There is a website for that called [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) for all your gaming questions.

Comment: Why are you answering this question, a question that lead to the creation of that website, nearly 6 years after it was asked.  Please pay attention!