# Game-related questions on SU

Tags: discussion, software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are video game questions appropriate for superuser?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/243/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are video game questions appropriate for superuser?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser)

At some level games are still software and you still have to use it.

I asked a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/73897/warcraft-3-replays) about how to **use** a specific game (making the question belong on Super**user**.com), but a couple of ninnies downvoted the question and want to close it.

I find this annoying and I don't think you should have the "purely video game or console related" option on the close box.  After all, games **are** software, and you do have to **use it** at some level.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser