# Are questions related to repairing a console on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics, video-games

[According to this](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/243/are-video-game-questions-appropriate-for-superuser/249#249) questions that are only about consoles are off-topic. However I was wondering if this is the same for questions that aren't about gaming, but rather repairing a console.

For example: My PS3 just got a [Yellow Light of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_3#Reliability) today and I was wondering if there is a way to tell which component is malfunctioning as I plan to repair this myself, rather then paying Sony $129.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Console questions are off-topic so the answer would be **no**

> If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or **consoles**
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except
>     insofar as they interface with your
>     computer
> - a shopping or buying recommendation

Comment: While I understand this answer, I do not agree with it. There was PC Repair SE proposal on Area 51 that was closed. It was closed because you can ask hardware related questions on Super User. I think questions about a console's **hardware** should be allowed since they are essential the same as computer hardware (or at least next gen console's are). I don't think we need a site solely for console hardware, but currently we have no place to ask these type of questions.

Comment: We don't have a site for non-Apple/Android gadgets either. Either way, both consoles run a proprietary OS over which nobody here has any control. What do you think we could do to help you?

Comment: @Ivo: Because my question isn't about an OS. It's about a hardware failure. The hardware in a PS3 or an Xbox360 is identical to PC hardware (and up until a few months ago you could run Linux on a PS3).

Comment: @IvoFlipse you have a better sense of this than I do - would it be appropriate on [gaming.se] or not?

Comment: Gaming would say its more appropriate here, because they're more about playing Games than fixing your console hardware. @Lucas, how do you expect to troubleshoot hardware without software? Its not like you can boot linux and see what works and what doesn't

Comment: @Ivo good point. If I could boot into Linux, would the question be appropriate for SU?

Comment: @Lucas Still, much too specific. Because we don't allow console questions, your chances of actually finding someone who can answer are relatively low. I would vote to close it -- even if it's hardware, it's much too specialized.

Comment: I would tend to agree that on Super User, this question would be both `off topic` and `too localized`.